# QComboBox and HeaderItem

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I have a `QComboBox` with a `QStandardItemModel`, which contains a single item named `One`.
I want the `QComboBox` to have an header (I’m not sure this is the correct technical term …) which will always be the same.
The following image depicts exactly what I want. Instead of having "One" next to the button that push down the list, I want "Header" printed (which is not an element of the list).
[image]

Important, the checkbox are mandatory (which is why I'm using QComboBox).

I tried the function `model.setHorizontalHeaderItem()` but it does not work (see the code below). 
Please, help me.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
QApplication app( argc, argv );
QComboBox* comboBox = new QComboBox();
QStandardItemModel model( 1, 1 );
QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem( QString("One") );
item->setFlags( Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled );
item->setData ( Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole );
model.setItem(0, 0, item);
model.setHorizontalHeaderItem( 0, new QStandardItem( "Header" ) );
comboBox->setModel( &model );
comboBox->show();

return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I think you need to create your own model and implement `headerData` member function. All the info you need is here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#model-headers-and-data

Comment: You need to set custom view to display drop-down content with headers.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I don't think he's referring to that header. I think he wants the combo box to display the header, and the dropdown to display the list view without the header...anyway it is unclear what he wants...

Comment: @luliu He wants to have a header. It is clear. Your comment about headerData function is useless.

Comment: I tried to explain clearly what I want above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
QTreeView *view = new QTreeView();
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel();

ui->comboBox->setModel( model );
ui->comboBox->setView( view );

for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem();
    const QString text = QString( "Item: %1" ).arg( i + 1 );
    item->setText( text );
    model->appendRow( item );
}

model->setHorizontalHeaderLabels( QStringList() << "It's a column" );
```

You will get something like this:
[image: ComboBox with header]

Now you can do all customization like with a standard `QTreeView`.

Comment: No, I deleted my answer. It is not solution. I just show how to set item with color and recommended dirty trick with signals and slots. Your answer is natural for Qt solution. I voted up it earlier.